# Why is the System tablespace in manual segment space management mode?

Tags: oracle

Why has Oracle kept the `SYSTEM` tablespace in manual segment space management mode? I searched on forums but didn't find the answer.

Comment: What version???

Answer (score 1):

Because Oracle says so :). The [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7003.htm#SQLRF54703) explicitly states that:

> Restrictions on Automatic Segment-Space Management This clause is
>   subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - You can specify this clause only for a permanent, locally managed tablespace.
> - You cannot specify this clause for the SYSTEM tablespace.

I don't know why, there are some hypothesis [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1074403?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: I've never even thought to question why, and won't. This is the answer :)

Comment: You can probably answer every Oracle question with "Because Oracle says so" :p